# Pass a list from Python to C with Ctypes and Python.h

Tags: python, c, ctypes, python-3.5

I am trying to pass an empty `result` list to a C function which can be modified and used later in Python. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
filename = askopenfilename()
result = []
status = self.lib.Cal_readFile(filename, result)
```

The `filename` argument is fine, however passing the result variable I get the error:

```
status = self.lib.Cal_readFile(filename, result)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

I am not surprised by the error as the ctypes docs state:

> As has been mentioned before, all Python types except integers,
>   strings, and unicode strings have to be wrapped in their corresponding
>   ctypes type, so that they can be converted to the required C data
>   type

Is there a way to fix this? I see no ctype for a list.

I essentially want to have a list that a C function will modify for me when called. It would work like how if I passed by reference a value in a C function and modified it, it would modify the original value.

Comment: C has no "list" type. You probably have to write your own C list library.

Comment: @franklin In C I would be using the `result` variable as a `PyObject`. I am using `python.h` in a wrapper function I have in C.

Comment: Do you develop both the C library and the Python code that loads it? If so, writing a Python module in C would probably a much easier way to go. In tutorials, you will also find hints how to pass any Python object and manipulate them in C code. Then, you can also write code that returns a tuple, like `status, result = plugin.read_file(filename)` or throw exceptions instead of returning error codes.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah it looks like that is what I want. I have created a new question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091759/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-trying-to-import-c-code-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ctypes.pydll` in tandem with `ctypes.py_object` as an argument type to allow passing native Python objects.

Here is a minimal example:

`test.c`

```
#include <Python.h>
extern int length(PyObject *obj)
{
    return PyObject_Length(obj);
}
```

And here is Python code using it:

```
>>> lib = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')
>>> lib.length.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
>>> lib.length([1,2,3])
3
>>> lib.length(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    lib.length(None)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

You must use `ctypes.pydll` and not `ctypes.cdll` if you are using the Python API inside your C code. This prevents the GIL from being released, and allows you to call Python API functions in your C code safely. Otherwise, the `lib.length(None)` call would have (likely) crashed the program.

Comment: So I was creating my lib using `self.lib =CDLL("./Cal.so")`. You're saying to use `PYDLL` instead then? What is the `lib.length.argtypes` line doing? My C function prototype looks like: `PyObject *Cal_readFile( PyObject *self, PyObject *args`

Comment: Less typing: `lib = ctypes.PyDLL('./test.so')`. It also lets you pass options if you need them, such as `mode`, `use_errno`, and `handle`.

Comment: @Fogest, that looks like a function defined in an extension module (i.e. `self` reference for the module; an `args` tuple parsed using `PyArg_ParseTuple`, and returning a `PyObject *`), so why don't you just create an extension? You're already requiring a compiler, so the case for ctypes is weak.

Comment: @Fogest Looks like you should be creating a Python extension module at this point.

Comment: @eryksun That is what I am trying to do, but I think I have gone astray to ctypes instead when I may not actually want that.

Comment: @eryksun Yeah, looks like I don't actually want ctypes.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it likely would have solved my original question, however it looks like I actually was looking for an answer to a whole different problem and have created a new question for that one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091759/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-trying-to-import-c-code-in